# Simple Example of ElasticSearch Index LifeCycle Policy in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Version of Elastic Search 7.10.2
and Xpack is enabled and the licence is Basic

#### Hot Phase of metricbeat policy

[image]

#### Delete Phase of metricbeat policy

[image]

#### WHY IS IT NOT GETTING APPLIED ?

[image]

#### metricbeat-7.10.2-2021.02.10-000001 index details

```sh
{
  "indices" : {
    "metricbeat-7.10.2-2021.02.10-000001" : {
      "index" : "metricbeat-7.10.2-2021.02.10-000001",
      "managed" : true,
      "policy" : "metricbeat",
      "lifecycle_date_millis" : 1612959479882,
      "age" : "8m",
      "phase" : "hot",
      "phase_time_millis" : 1612959480192,
      "action" : "rollover",
      "action_time_millis" : 1612959917863,
      "step" : "check-rollover-ready",
      "step_time_millis" : 1612959917863,
      "phase_execution" : {
        "policy" : "metricbeat",
        "phase_definition" : {
          "min_age" : "0ms",
          "actions" : {
            "rollover" : {
              "max_size" : "5b",
              "max_age" : "5s",
              "max_docs" : 5
            }
          }
        },
        "version" : 2,
        "modified_date_in_millis" : 1612959551839
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you get from `GET metricbeat-7.10.2-2021.02.10-000001/_ilm/explain`?

Comment: @val, Thanks for responding, just added the output of the newly created index which behaves the same way.

Comment: Did you change the policy definition after index creation? Or was the policy already defined like that and the index was created with that policy right from the beginning?

Comment: yes I did change the policy defination of lifecycle policy `metricbeat`. I want to do a smallest possible example demonstrating how lifecycle policy works. I am using [this](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/docker-compose-kitchen/tree/master/local-mac/task-009-natsStreaming-metricbeat-elasticsearch-kibana) to simulate but with latest version of images.

Comment: What happens if you delete that index and create a new index? If a policy is modified AFTER an index has been created, it might not kick in as you expect: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/update-lifecycle-policy.html#ilm-apply-changes

Comment: Yes I deleted the index and with the new index its taking effect BUT strangely all counts (Doc, Size, Age) are much more than the threshold. How can I apply the policy to existing index? Most of the time indexes are already created and we need to assign policies to them.

Comment: ILM runs every 10 minutes by default, but that can be changed (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-index-lifecycle.html#ilm-phase-execution)

Comment: Ah okay. Now it makes sense then. So, unless this field is modified (from 10 mins), the indexes would at least stay untouched 10 to mins before ILM kicks in to take effect.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

If a policy is modified AFTER an index has been created, it [might not kick in](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/update-lifecycle-policy.html#ilm-apply-changes) as you expect.

ILM runs [every 10 minutes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-index-lifecycle.html#ilm-phase-execution) by default, but that can be changed via the `indices.lifecycle.poll_interval` cluster setting.